# Raphael Change Direction Animation

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to get a circle to run the following animations:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 1280,600);

var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 20);

circle.animate({
                cx: 200
            }, 2000)

circle.animate({
                cx: 600,
                    cy: 400
            }, 2000)
```

However I ONLY want the second animation to run AFTER the first one has been completed. Is there a function that can accomplish this easily or do I have to set delays, etc...?

Comment: You should probably accept the answers to your questions. People will stop answering you if you ignore them.

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that, Brian. I am new to SOF :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DktHL/454/)**

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 1280,600);
var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 20);

circle.animate({ cx: 200}, 2000, hideCircle);

function hideCircle()
{
    circle.animate({cx: 600,cy: 400}, 2000);
}
```